# How to create a custom field that hold a mixture of HTML & PHP code and attach it to a user

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create HTML table data for users. I need the HTML like so. How I intend to use this? I'm looking at echoing rows of user data one at a time so I don't really need a foreach or anything like that. Therefore, I added one more custom field to the users called `user_row`.

This is where I have trouble going forward - displaying the data below in the said `user_row` field. I used ACF Plugin to create the fields. The `user_row` field displays in the Add/Edit Page of the user but it's blank.

What I have here below displays the data for the logged in user but if I can somehow attach it to the `user_row` ACF field the it will be possible for me to list the users.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
$tm_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<tr>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->first_name . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->last_name . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->town_city .' '. $tm_user->state_county . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->tel_number . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->website . '<br />'; ?></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Andwer based on below reference:

You can use the ACF `get_field()` function.

```
<?php 
$tm_user = wp_get_current_user();
the_field( 'field_name', 'user_' . $tm_user ); 

?>
```

Reference

ACF `the_field()`
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/

`wp_get_current_user()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

Comment: It returns NULL - using var_dump. The field ```user_row``` is still blank.

Comment: I think it's empty because the $tm_user needs to be something along the lines of (put simply) ```$tm_user = '<table>
<tbody>
<?php
$tm_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<tr>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->first_name . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->last_name . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->town_city .' '. $tm_user->state_county . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->tel_number . '<br />'; ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $tm_user->website . '<br />'; ?></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>'```. I know you cannot just create a variable like that. In a proper way?

Comment: Do you get a return on `var_dump( $tm_user );`

Comment: Can you add the var dump for tm_user to your question and I'll try reply later.

Comment: Var_dump on $tm_user ```object(WP_User)#955 (8) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#887 (10) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "20" ["user_login"]=> string(6) "Tem15" ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$BHcFNnZbbCEmEPVr3Uu." ["user_nicename"]=> string(6) "tem15" ["user_email"]=> string(18) "temsbnug@gmail.com" ["user_url"]=> string(0) "" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2020-07-30 22:06:14" ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0) "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_name"]=> string(15) "Tem15 jjdbjbug" } ["ID"]=> int(20) ["caps"]=> array(1) { ["temp"]=> bool(true) } ["cap_key"]=> string(15) "wp_capabilities" ...

Comment: Maybe this is what I am looking for, but I don't know how to get there - To save the above fields ```first_name, last_name, town_city, state_county, tel_number, website``` in the ```field_name``` meta value as an array in the database. And then pull the data using index into the html table. I really feel this is what I am looking. Because you cannot save all the html code plus php code inside the database. Saving the data of interest as an array can allow me to pull it into the html. Any road there?

Comment: I've read your post again. You cant/shouldnt save additional details like html code in the input, just the input value, and then when you write your code, you include that html before and after the input (like you have in your example). The usermeta is just the details in that var_dump, but if you want to get `first_name` for example you'll have to use `the_field( 'first_name', 'user_' . $tm_user->ID );` or `the_field( 'first_name', $tm_user->ID );` (I cant test it on my phone).